# ExtJS/MODx CMP: grid edits not saving to db, combo box not displaying

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs3, modx-revolution, datagridcomboboxcolumn

ExtJS, or MODext, is a difficult subject with little documentation, so I'm coming here for some assistance. I have 2 issues, both within the same code.

Basic summary, I have a single page with 2 tabs displaying info from 2 different custom tables. The 2 tabs (respectively: Clients, Budgets) are displaying well, the grids with the info are almost entirely displaying properly. Almost...

**Firstly**: I have a combo that is extending MODx.combo to display the full names of users with the username as the value, and have referenced the Ext.util renderer to display the values. On the Budgets tab (2nd tab) this works fine, but on the Clients tab (1st tab) the display won't render out (the combo still displays on double-click. Here's my codes...

Firstly the extension:

```
GR8.combo.User = function(config) {
    config = config || {};
    Ext.applyIf(config,{
    id: 'user'
        ,name: 'user'
        //,hiddenName: 'user'
        ,displayField: 'fullname'
        ,valueField: 'username'
        ,fields: ['fullname','username']
        ,pageSize: 20
        ,url: MODx.config.connectors_url+'security/user.php'
        ,typeAhead: true
        ,editable: true
    });
    GR8.combo.User.superclass.constructor.call(this,config);
};
Ext.extend(GR8.combo.User,MODx.combo.ComboBox);
Ext.reg('gr8-combo-user',GR8.combo.User);
```

Next, the combo field code for the Clients grid:

```
{
   header: 'Agent'
   ,dataIndex: 'clientAgent'   //equates to modx username
   ,sortable: true
   ,width: 60
   ,editor: { xtype: 'gr8-combo-user' ,renderer: true}
   ,renderer: Ext.util.Format.comboRenderer(GR8.combo.User, 'clientAgent')
}
```

Finally, the combo field code for the Budgets grid:

```
{
   header: 'Agent'
   ,dataIndex: 'budgAgent'
   ,sortable: true
   ,width: 60
   ,editor: { xtype: 'gr8-combo-user' ,renderer: true}
   ,renderer: Ext.util.Format.comboRenderer(GR8.combo.User, 'budgAgent')
}
```

Am I missing something, or is there an issue here that's not easy to see?

**Secondly**: When I do make a change to the grid, the change isn't saved - the little red triangle stays in the top left corner of the field in the grid. I've found a save button I think I can use from the MODx Gallery component:

```
,formpanel: 'gr8-panel-home'
,buttons: [{
    text: _('save')
    ,id: 'gr8-btn-save'
    ,process: 'mgr/gr8/update'
    ,method: 'remote'
    ,keys: [{
        key: 's'
        ,alt: true
        ,ctrl: true
    }]
}]
```

This puts a save button on the page (it also duplicates the search input :( ), but I'm guess there's some more I need to do with it. Can someone show me what I need to do please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save grid after you update a row directly from grid, you need to add these two params to grid definition:

```
,save_action: 'path/to/update/from/grid/processor'
,autosave: true
```

Here is the example of updatefromgrid processor: https://github.com/modxcms/Tagger/blob/master/core/components/tagger/processors/mgr/tag/updatefromgrid.class.php

Comment: This works - thanks; your example from Tagger was super-useful. Now I have a problem where the id field is not named 'id', rather is named 'budgId', and MODx thinks that there isn't an id field for the table, so it throws and err_ns error and won't save. If you have any thoughts on that, I'd appreciate it. I've posted this in the MODx forums: [link]http://forums.modx.com/thread/92029/custom-tables-save-to-db---redefine-primary-key[/link]. Maybe @MarkHamstra might have a clue too...

Comment: Save is solved, see the link above for inof on how I redfined the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

In your combobox, you give it a hardcoded id of "user". Get rid of that and you should be ready to go.

ExtJS doesn't handle components with the same IDs, so the second time the combo is built it simply freaks out and doesn't know what to do. Sometimes it duplicates things when it shares an ID, sometimes it throws an error and does nothing.

@TheBoxer already addressed your second problem; adding `autosave` and `save_action` should do the trick for that.

Comment: Neither of these worked. I'll sort out with @TheBoxer regarding the save function. The combo box however, showed no change by removing the id from either combo box. The initial display of the combo in the first tab is still not displaying on page load, while the second one is.

Comment: Just to confirm, this suggestion didn't make any difference to the combobox. Does anyone have any other ideas?